# How to change prettyCheckable checkbox with jquery (check and uncheck)

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

How do i change prettyCheckable checkbox with jquery, to check and uncheck?
I tried everything.. 
Actually i'm able to change, the checkbox checks and unchecks, but visually doesn't change..
I tried numerous ways:

```
$('#part_PAC-050-0142').attr('checked', true); 
$('#part_PAC-050-0142').attr("checked","checked");
$('#part_PAC-050-0142').prop("checked", true).change();
$("ul > li > div > href", "#radio_parts").addClass("checked");
$('#part_PAC-050-0142').addClass("checked", true);
$('#part_PAC-050-0142').triggerHandler("click");

$('input.prettyC').prettyCheckable();
```

None of this worked, none changed visually the prettyCheckable checkbox..

Comment: $('#part_PAC-050-0142').prop("checked", true) remove .change()

Comment: Having the same problem. The author of the answer below doesn't even get the question.

Comment: Definitely needs to be in the documentation: To check one of the radio buttons, use `$('input#field').prettyCheckable('check');` You might need `$("input#field").trigger('change');` to update your values.

Comment: a jsFiddle of PrettyCheckable 2.0.0 to get you started with your experiments https://jsfiddle.net/4pdzw2Lg/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

if u are using jquery version **jquery 1.6 +** use `prop` else use `attr`

Here i think remove `.change()`

```
$('#part_PAC-050-0142').prop("checked", true).change();
```

TO:

```
$('#part_PAC-050-0142').prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use pretty checkable functions:

```
$('#part_PAC-050-0142').prettyCheckable('check');
```

and

```
$('#part_PAC-050-0142').prettyCheckable('uncheck');
```

Comment: You might want to add a jsFiddle example of your solution by editing this base https://jsfiddle.net/4pdzw2Lg/

Comment: This should be the `accepted answer` because is the one that works with the prettyCheckable plugin